# Undefined property: Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ParameterBag::$product_id"

Tags: php, laravel

This is a laravel vue project. I want to update my Cart.
Request sending to controller look like [image]

My Controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $carts = Auth::user()->carts;
        foreach ($carts as $cart){
           $cart->delete();
        };

        foreach ($request as $data){
            $newCart = new Cart();
            $newCart->user_id = Auth::id();
            $newCart->product_id = $data->product_id;
            $newCart->variant_id = $data->variant_id;
            $newCart->color_id = $data->color_id;
            $newCart->quantity = $data->quantity;
            $newCart->save();
        }

        return response()->json('Cart Successfully Updated',200);
    }
```

Now Why I'm facing Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::$product_id" error

Comment: A `Request` is an object that has public properties so when you iterate it you get them, not the inputs ... you are probably looking to iterate `$request->all()` or `$request->json()`

Comment: Thanks #lagbox, $request->all() is working Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "your/route",
  type: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  data: JSON.stringify([{"id":13,"user":1,"product":4},{"id":4,"user":8,"product":4},{"id":6,"user":90,"product":23}]),
  success: function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Assuming you are submitting an ajax request with the above settings and data, you can easily go through it in your controller like:

```
foreach ($request->all() as $data){
    // your code here.
    // You can access each item's data like: $data->id, $data->user etc.
}
```